# Ruby on Rails - User input for sort ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In order to learn Ruby on Rails I am writing a web app that will be used to sort teams within a tournament given their performance to date.

The complication is that I want each tournament organiser (system user) to be able to use a variety of metrics in an arbitrary order.

Expressed as SQL (my background) I want User 1 to be able to choose:

```
ORDER BY
   METRIC1
  ,METRIC2
  ,METRIC3
```

Whilst User 2 could choose:

```
ORDER BY
   METRIC2
  ,METRIC3
  ,METRIC1
```

---

**How would I accept this user input and use it to create a query on the Team table?**

---

**Edit 1** Neglected to mention (sorry) that the metrics themselves are calculated on the fly. Currently they are instance methods (e.g `@team.metric1` etc). The abortive attempts I have made so far all involve trying to convert user strings to method names which just seems wrong (and I haven't been able to get it to work).

**Edit 2** some example code in teams_controller.rb:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tournament
  has_many :matches

  def score_for
    matches.sum(:score_for)
  end
  def score_diff
    matches.sum(:score_for) - matches.sum(:score_against)
  end
end
```

Comment: @engineersmnky, sorry, my question was lacking. Hopefully the update makes it clearer? Not sure how to do `Team.order(@team.<userselect>,@team.<userselect>)` and not at all sure that I should be!

Comment: Ahhhh now I understand. Can you please post some code as to what these metrics are and how you are submitting the user input (`params`) it will make it easier to help

Comment: I'll post some code for the metrics but I haven't written the rest as I haven't worked out an approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working but probably awful solution:

```
class Tournament < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :teams

  serialize :tiebreaker, Array

  TIEBREAKER_WHITELIST = %w[score opponent_score possession].freeze

  def sorted_teams
    list = teams.shuffle
    (TIEBREAKER_WHITELIST & tiebreaker).reverse.each do |metric|
      list = list.sort_by { |team| [team.send(metric), list.find_index(team)] }
    end
    list.reverse
  end
end
```

Each `tournament` has many `teams`. A `tournament` instance has a serialized field called `tiebreaker`. This contains an array of strings something like `["score", "possession"]` where each string matches the name of a public instance method on `team`. Each of these methods returns a number.

The `tiebreaker` field is in descending order of precedence, so for the above example I would only expect `possession` to affect sorting for teams with an equal `score`.

**`list = teams.shuffle`** - this randomises the list to start with, in case teams are tied for all of the following tiebreakers.

**`(TIEBREAKER_WHITELIST & tiebreaker)`** - this returns only strings that appear in both the `tiebreaker` field and the whitelist constant to protect against end users running arbitrary methods.

**`.reverse.each do |metric|`** - this reverses the array of metrics so that the list is sorted by the lowest precedence metric first.

**`[team.send(metric), list.find_index(team)]`** - this is the sort for each metric. `send` turns the string into a method call. I found `find_index`was necessary to preserver sort order from previous sorts. i.e. if I had first sorted for `possession` this would preserve the order for teams with the same `score`.

**`list.reverse`** - reverse the list then return it. This was because I wanted higher scoring/possession teams first on my list and `sort_by` sorts ascending.

I wanted some metrics sorted ascending (`opponent_score`) and others descending (`score`) so I handled this in the respective methods, returning negative values for `opponent_score` for example.

I'm not entirely happy with the solution as is but it does seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord allows multiple arguments to be passed to the order method. So you could do something like:

`Team.order(:metric2, :metric3, metric1: :desc)`

Another options is you can also use ActiveRecord to dynamically construct a query. ActiveRecord queries are lazily evaluated, so the SQL won't be executed until you call an operation that requires loading the records.

For example you could construct a scope on Team like this:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord

  scope :custom_order, lambda { |sorting_order|
    sorting_order.each do |metric|
      order(metric)
    end
  }
end
```

You would then just need to input a collection of attributes in the order you wanted the order by clauses to be executed. For example:

`Team.custom_order([:metric2, :metric3, :metric1])`

Comment: Per the question: metrics are not database values but instead are calculated on a per instance basis

Comment: Yes, I originally missed that potentially crucial point out! sorry